# How to restrict read only to Authorized users of Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am modifying the [FriendlyPix](https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix) Firebase sample app so that only authenticated and authorized user can read data under the node. Following is the Database rule for my real-time DB

```
 "posts": {
    //  ".read": true, COMMENTED OUT
      "$postId": {
          ".read": "auth.uid === data.child('author').child('uid').val()",
         ".write": "!data.exists() || data.exists() && auth.uid === data.child('author').child('uid').val()", 
//more code
```

The issue is that now a logged-in user can't read any posts (not even the ones he posted). I am using Firebase UI and Google login. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: aren't you missing starting `"` in ` ".read": auth.uid === data.child('author').child('uid').val()",`. should it be like `".read": "auth.uid === data.child('author').child('uid').val()",`

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I've fixed that...still can't read data

Answer (score 1):

Without the line you commented out, nobody can read from `/posts`. To be able to query `/posts`. you must be able to read from it.

This a common recurring roadblock for developers new to Firebase: rules cannot be used to filter data. I recommend you read up on that in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) and in the many [questions on the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+rules+are+not+filters).

Answer (score 1):

Firebase queries are all or nothing. If you are listening to the "/posts" node of your Firebase database, a user will only get ANY data if the are authorized to see ALL of the data under that node. Your rules do allow for an author to read their own posts, but not any others. This means that the entire query will result in an authentication error.

Anytime `auth` is not null, it means the user is authenticated. As any authenticated user should be able to read a post, just putting read to "auth != null" will suffice. Note that this only allows logged in users to read posts, not to edit them.